# trackchanges VS latexdiff

Tags: latexdiff, changes

I am trying to decide whether to choose [`trackchanges`](http://trackchanges.sourceforge.net/) or [`latexdiff`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff) for corrections on my thesis. Can anyone tell me their views? I have had problems with `latexdiff` choking on equations (is there any easy way out of that?).

When someone says

```
"compile it with track-change option"
```

do they mean specifically trackchange or could it also be for latexdiff?

Comment: It's not necessary to begin your questions with a greeting.

Comment: Are both not quite different? `latexdiff` marks changes between two versions of a file automatically and `trackchanges` seems to be for manually tracking changes, or do I see that wrong?

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: they are different, I have only used one and want to know if there is any need to try Trackchanges.

Comment: @Martin: Could you make your comment here an answer? It's as close as we are likely to come to one!

Comment: @Joseph: Now done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both packages seem to be quite different. `latexdiff` marks changes between two versions of a file automatically and `trackchanges` seems to be for manually tracking changes.

I don't think a person telling you to "compile it with track-change option" means automatically to use the `trackchanges` packages. I would just ask this person if you are in doubt. You should be able to review made changes, so I would recommend to use a version control software like Subversion or Git or one of the many others so you can access older versions easily. I personally use then `latexdiff` to display the differences between two revisions.